# Convert String "10.20" to Double and then to Int at once in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

I'm trying to convert the String "10.20" to Int without converting it to Double before.

I want to get the value: **10**

At the moment what is working is:

```
    let valueString  = "10.20"
    let valueInt = Int(Double(valueString)!)
    print(valueInt)
```

But, is there any better way to do it?

I was trying first to do it with this command but was returning **nil**:

```
    let valueString  = "10.20"
    let valueInt = Int(valueString)
    print(valueInt)
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's a better way. Remove the ! so that your app doesn't crash on non-numeric input.

Comment: If I remove it I have an error: "Value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped

Answer (score 0):

You could just put an extension on the Int type that makes it StringLiteralConvertable, producing the expected result via a Float cast behind the scenes.